# Binary classifier has only learned features from class A, it actually categorize samples as class B if it does not belong to Class A

Tags: pytorch, classification, feature-extraction

I am currently in the process of training a binary classifier that utilizes a combination of CNN-LSTM in Pytorch. Thus far, the model has performed fine, achieving a classification accuracy of 99 percent. However, the classifier seems to has only learned features from class A, leading it to label all other samples as class B. What steps can I take to ensure that the classifier learns features from both classes?

I have tried to change the problem to multi-class multi-label but that didn't help with finding features from class B.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.